# Synonyms for \bfseries and \itshape and such?

Tags: fonts, formatting

Seeing as it is quite [confusing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/bfseries-is-to-textbf-as-what-is-to-textsf) for non-TeX expert to know how to specify *italic* or *bold* font, and the names such as `\bfseries` are not straightforward...

Is there a package that defines synonyms like `\bold` and `\italic`, so one can just do:

```
{\bold\italic My text}
```

If not - why? Just curious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Provided that no other package defines `\bold` and `\italics` and the like, you can include

```
\let\bold\bfseries
\let\italics\itshape
```

in your preamble. This would equate the definition of `\bfseries` with `\bold` (and others) at the time of call, allowing you to use them as you wish:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\bold\bfseries
\let\italics\itshape
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
{\bfseries\itshape Here is some text.} \par
Here is some text. \par
{\bold\italics Here is some text.}
\end{document}​
```

Why have something like `\bfseries` and not `\bold` or plain old `\bf`? For me, [Will Robertson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15369/5764) to [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764) makes the most sense and is based on the distinction between formatting decisions and content.

Comment: Thanks! His answer seems to imply that I shouldn't use `itshape` in my document if I want to have an italic word - like for the name of the city or a scientific term.. What should I use?

Comment: @drozzy: If you type something like `\bfseries` or `\itshape` very often, it is actually better to define a new command that describes why you're changing the font. E.g., `\let\keywordstyle\bfseries` or `\newcommand{\mykeyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` (see [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764) to [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)). That way you can modify `\keywordstyle` or `\mykeyword` and it will roll out to the remainder of your document without individually modifying the respective `\bfseries` or `\textbf` usages. It promotes consistency.