# Combining sffamily and scshape

Tags: fonts, small-caps, sans-serif

According to [a relevant comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/bfseries-is-to-textbf-as-what-is-to-textsf#comment12418_7670), one should be able to specify both weights and shapes for each family.
Why can I (seemingly) not have small caps with `\sffamily`?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\scshape Test
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Neither Computer Modern Sans nor Latin Modern Sans have a small caps font.

Comment: A font with the specifics must exist. If not LaTeX will fall back to a substitute. You can get sans serif small caps e.g with libertine.

Comment: [meta:] how is the big second example relevant to your question? I think the first one illustrates your problem just fine, maybe in combination with an [image.](http://i.imgur.com/49oXLbi.png) (been thinking about editing it out, but I thought I'd bring it up first)

Comment: @NilsL Go right ahead; as I was writing this question, I didn't have access to a TeX distribution --- I only noticed the issue while writing the answer to the linked last night.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, in the context of egreg's comment, that makes sense now.  Is there no way to coerce LaTeX into performing the unspoken atrocities of cheap sc-imitation?

Comment: @SeanAllred Imitation of small caps by reducing the uppercase letters can, in some rare cases, give a result just above the atrocious level. With CM Sans such an attempt is doomed to horrible failure, because the heavy strokes are a distinctive feature of the font and you'd be mixing very different strokes between capitals and small capitals. I suggest using spaced all capitals (you get them easily with `microtype`).

Comment: This works with certain font families, e.g. `palatino`

Comment: @egreg Please make an answer here :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imitation of small caps by reducing the uppercase letters can, in some rare cases, give a result slightly above the atrocious level. With Computer Modern Sans Serif such an attempt is doomed to horrible failure, because the heavy strokes are a distinctive feature of the font and you'd be mixing very different strokes between capitals and small capitals. I suggest using spaced all capitals (you get them easily with `microtype`).

This is an example with Computer Modern, European Modern and Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\hsc}[1]{{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
T\hsc{his} \hsc{is} F\hsc{ake} S\hsc{mall} C\hsc{aps}

\fontencoding{T1}
T\hsc{his} \hsc{is} F\hsc{ake} S\hsc{mall} C\hsc{aps}

\fontfamily{lmss}
T\hsc{his} \hsc{is} F\hsc{ake} S\hsc{mall} C\hsc{aps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apart from the missing kerns, the contrast between the F and the A is too visible and horrible.

Comment: Horrible indeed; is there a way to convince `microtype` to take care of this?

Comment: @SeanAllred Sorry, if the font doesn't support small caps, there's not much to do.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is a version of computer modern with small caps in the `sansmathfonts` package.  You can use it follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notmath]{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\textsc{Is This Better Than Fake Small Caps?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fine. but works only with pdfTeX, not with LuaTeX nor XeTeX.

Answer (score 1):

With LuaTeX or XeTeX and fontspec this works out of the box (maybe the font has to support it, but at least with Libertinus):

```latex
\documentclass[convert,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}
Normal Text \\
{\sffamily sffamily Text} \\
{\scshape scshape Text} \\
{\sffamily\scshape sffamily scshape Text} \\
\end{document}
```

This yields

[image: document output]