# How do I get slanted text (\sl) with a different font (Times New Roman)?

Tags: fonts, cv, resume, times, slanted

I came across the `\sl` command to slant certain fonts. With the default CMU Serif font, it looks nice. However, one of my professors uses Times New Roman to do his CV (in LaTeX), and I want to mimic that style. However, when I try to use `\sl` with Times New Roman (using `setmainfont{Times New Roman}`), it just uses the standard italics for TNR. Is there a specific command that I'm missing or some style that I need to add? If a picture would help, I can add one. Thanks!

Comment: This should answer your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128562/how-to-use-fakeslant-as-slanted-but-not-italic-font-with-fontspec

Comment: @DonHosek yes, that did solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not all fonts are available in all variants. (La)TeX (through the New Font Selection Scheme, NFSS) knows about families (general shape of the font), shapes (upright, slanted, italic), series (bold, regular). Not all (essentially independent aspects) of a font family are always available (e.g. the computer modern family was carefully designed so that frobbing all knobs independently is possible, others are redoing historic fonts which just didn't have all variants, or even any). For example, Times New Roman is (surprise!) the new roman (upright) font in use by the newspaper The Times. A more detailed discussion in the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371931/21275) question.

Comment: Then... it makes me wonder: how exactly did he accomplish this? Here's the CV I'm referring to: https://www.uncg.edu/cmp/faculty/srtate/TateVita.pdf - take a look at the running header starting on page 2: "Stephen R. Tate". How is it slanted like that in TNR?