# What is the fastest way to make following table in tex?

Tags: tables

I tried

```
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{\small{Denomination}} \quad &\textbf{\small{Scope in weeks}} \quad &\textbf{\small{Grade}}\\
&\text{Native language, literature} &7 &3
\end{align*}
```

But numbers do not align properly.

What would be fastest way to produce similar table ?

[image: table]

Comment: `align` is a math display you want `tabular` here, with `\begin{tabular}{lr;}` for the three columns,

Comment: If your table is longer than one page, you might also want to use the `longtable` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get error

`Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. [&\textbf{\small{Denomination}} \quad &]`

Comment: @flowian: Remove the first `&` sign. A MWE:  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lrl}
\textbf{\small{Denomination}}  &\textbf{\small{Scope in weeks}}  &\textbf{\small{Grade}}\\
Native language, literature &7 &3

\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: also the `;` in my first comment was supposed to be an `l` sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haha! I read the first comment and thought »I've never seen this in all these years!« and really wondered what »;« could stand for.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, worked like a charm.

Comment: @leandriis Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 4):

an alternative option, slightly more "sophisticated":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,  % for case if table is longer than one page
            makecell}   % for columns headers
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}  % column header font definition
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for S column type, numbers are aligned at decimal point

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.1]l}
\thead{Denomination}        & {\thead{Scope\\ in weeks}} &\thead{Grade} \\
Native language, literature & 7     & 3 (rahuldav)                      \\
some topic                  & 0.5   & 3 (rahuldav)                      \\
Microprocessor engineering  & 2.5   & 5 (viga hea)
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

in case if you need \verb+longtable+:

\begin{longtable}{lS[table-format=1.1]l}
\thead{Denomination}        & {\thead{Scope\\ in weeks}} &\thead{Grade} \\
Native language, literature & 7     & 3 (rahuldav)                      \\
some topic                  & 0.5   & 3 (rahuldav)                      \\
Microprocessor engineering  & 2.5   & 5 (viga hea)
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum**:
some people prefer if the column header are vertically aligned at theirs bottoms:

[image]

this cab be done with use of the `\thead[b]{...}` instead of `\thead{...}` in the first tables rows in above *mwe* (minimal working example):

```
\thead[b]{Denomination} & {\thead[b]{Scope\\ in weeks}} &\thead[b]{Grade} \\
```

Answer (score 2):

The following small example should give you an idea how to start:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{lrl} 
\textbf{\small Denomination} &\textbf{\small Scope in weeks} &\textbf{\small Grade}\\ Native language, literature &7 &3 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the contents in the first column are too long and the table no longer fits into the textwidth, you might want to use `tabularx`. If the whole table is longer than a single page, the `longtable` environment might be useful.

Comment: Please note that the font size switches don’t take an argument thus `\small{text}` must be `{\small text}` if you want to fence the effect of the change. In your example it doesn’t matter, since the table cell is a group already and the font change is only active in the cell. See also “Font switch vs. Text command” in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139592/4918.